# Identifying the element moused over in an onmouseover function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to create one function that will change the class of one of three elements when the mouse goes over that particular element (and only that element).

However whenever I mouse over any element, the class changes for all three. Why? Here's what I did:

<-- The HTML -->

```
<p class="font1" id="change4_1" onmouseover="Q4()"> Menu1</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_2" onmouseover="Q4()"> Menu2</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_3" onmouseover="Q4()"> Menu3</p>
```

/* The CSS*/

```
p.font1 {
    color:blue;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
p.font2 {
    color:#2E2E2E;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

// The Javascript //

```
function Q4() {
    var NAME1 = document.getElementById("change4_1");
    if (NAME1.mouseover = true) {
        NAME1.className = "font2";
    }

    var NAME2 = document.getElementById("change4_2");
    if (NAME2.mouseover = true) {
        NAME2.className = "font2";
    }

    var NAME3 = document.getElementById("change4_3");
    if (NAME3.mouseover = true) {
        NAME3.className = "font2";
    }
}
```

I'm certain the JavaScript is the issue but I included everything anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare use [**==(Equality Operator)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_%28%29) or [**===(Strict Equality Operator)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_%28%29).

You're not comparing the value in the `if` statement. You're assigning the value `true` to the variable. To compare the value in the `if` statement, use `==` or `===` operator.

```
if (NAME1.mouseover=true)
```

Should be

```
if (NAME1.mouseover == true)
```

Or

```
if (NAME1.mouseover === true)
```

---

You don't need Javascript to change styles on mouseover, you can take advantage of CSS `:hover` class.

```css
p.font1 {
  color: blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
p.font1:hover {
  color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

```html
<p class="font1" id="change4_1">Menu1</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_2">Menu2</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_3">Menu3</p>
```

**Update**

As your JS code is invalid, `NAME1.mouseover = true`, you can use following code, if you want to use JS to change some properties of HTML element on mouseover.(I'll still recommend to use *CSS approach*)

```js
function Q4(el) {
  el.classList.add('font2');
}
```

```css
p.font1 {
  color: blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
p.font2 {
  color: #2E2E2E;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="font1" id="change4_1" onmouseover="Q4(this)">Menu1</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_2" onmouseover="Q4(this)">Menu2</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_3" onmouseover="Q4(this)">Menu3</p>
```

Comment: @TGreenwood If you read my answer carefully, I've added javascript answer also. If you need to add the class, use the first approach, if you just want to style on hover, use CSS approach

Comment: I don't understand. `if (NAME1.mouseover == true)` is going to return the value of a `mouseover` property on `NAME1`, which is different from the question of whether `NAME1` is the element being mouse overed.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the element's `mouseover` property to `true` in each if statement. This is successful and equates to being `true` so each if statement is being run. You can't test the element's `mouseover` property because that's not part of the DOM for elements.

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to change your CSS's `p.font2` to `p.font1:hover`

However, if you're trying to learn about triggering JavaScript functions with mouseover try passing the argument `this` to the onmouseover function, IE `Q4(this)`. The function can then refer to the element that was moused over more directly.

```html
<html><head>
<style>
p.font1 {
    color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
p.font2 {
    color: #2E2E2E;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<script>
function Q4(element)
{
    element.className='font2';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="font1" id="change4_1" onmouseover="Q4(this)"> Menu1</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_2" onmouseover="Q4(this)"> Menu2</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_3" onmouseover="Q4(this)"> Menu3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This won't change the style back on mouse out though. You could easily write that attribute too.

Since that boils down to one line of code, you could just change it to `onmouseover="this.className='font2';"`

Most people adding JavaScript event handlers wind up using something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to help them keeping the script separate from the markup (the CSS only `:hover` selector does that too). I've demonstrated that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jtpoma7w/) and below:

```html
<html><head>
<style>
p.font1 {
    color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
p.font2 {
    color:#2E2E2E;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "p.font1" ).on({
        "mouseover": function() {
            console.log( "hovered!" );
            var elem = $( this );
            elem.addClass( "font2" );
        },
        "mouseout": function() {
            console.log( "unhovered!" );
            var elem = $( this );
            elem.removeClass( "font2" );
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="font1" id="change4_1"> Menu1</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_2"> Menu2</p>
<p class="font1" id="change4_3"> Menu3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What this does, apart from loading the jQuery library and binding it to `$`, is, when the document is loaded and ready, it selects all the elements that are of type `p` with the class `font1` and adds event handler functions to them for the `mouseover` event and `mouseout` event. These functions in turn log to the JavaScript console when triggered (useful when you're debugging some of your work), get the referring element on which the event was triggered, and then either add or remove a class name to the elements class attribute. So you would see the `p` tag's class change from `"font1"` to `"font1 font2"` and back. That's why the font2 css is changed to only override the specifically changed color.

I hope this better explains what was going on in your example, and what to do about it.

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks!  `Q4(this)` is one I didn't know, and adding `element` inside the function tag coupled with `element.className='font2';` solved my problem.     CSS method is most efficient but this was a learning exercise for my Java skills (or lack thereof) more than anything. Much appreciated

Comment: @TGreenwood I'm glad it helped; so, to make it easier for you to follow up on the approaches learned: the function tag is called a parameter and in the case of JavaScript you can use any word that is not a reserved word (those are like the word "function" or "if", also "this"). `this` is a very useful keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this